# Not able to see the resource folder and custom.property file in recent release of Spartacus

Tags: spartacus-storefront

I am new to Spartacus and was following the https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2005/ to do the localsetup for Hybris 2005 but not finding the resourse folder and custom.property file in the new releases .
Please help on the above asking.
Thank you in advance .

Comment: Which zip file exactly you are referring to? I also suggest to tag this question with "hybris" tag.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have to create the `custom.properties` file.  At the bottom of the page, the guide suggests the content to add in the `custom.properties` file.

See https://sap.github.io/spartacus-docs/installing-sap-commerce-cloud-2005/#configproperties-file